# Reactive object in Vue 3 Composition API not updating with a @click event

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-reactivity

I seem to be missing something with the Vue Composition API when it comes to using and updating reactive objects.

See the below code. I'm expecting the click event to update the `{{colors}}` output in the template when a color is added.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <!-- {{colors}} Is not updated in the DOM on click event -->
    <pre>{{ colors }}</pre>
    <button @click="addColor">add color</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { reactive } from 'vue';

export default {
  setup() {
    let colors = reactive({ green: '#ccc000' });

    function addColor() {
      // By cloning and creating a new merged object
      colors = Object.assign({}, colors, { red: '#fff000' });
      // Or by changing the object directly
      colors.orange = '#322332'; // Also does not work
      console.log(colors); // Logs out the correct value
    }

    return {
      colors,
      addColor,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

I can see in the console log the value of colors is being updated but not in the DOM.

Here is a code sandbox of the code

https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-roentgen-rox9k?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: I checked sandbox  link you provided.  In the sandbox , the DOM is updated by click!

Answer (score 2):

You probably shouldn't create a new object:

```
colors = Object.assign({}, colors, { red: '#fff000' });
```

Instead, try to manipulate the existing object:

```
delete colors.green;
colors.red = '#fff000';
```

Comment: I actually updated my example a little earlier showing exactly what you suggested as it also does not work. edit: I removed the Object assign line and it works

Comment: Instead of the `colors = Object.assign()`, not in addition.

Comment: @AndyJamesN You've replaced your reactive proxy with a normal object. That's why it didn't react when you manipulated it directly.

Comment: and by the way, a cooler syntax for `colors = Object.assign...` would be `colors = { ...colors, red: '#fff000' }` :)

Comment: Yes that makes sense! Before object assign I was using the spread operator to merge but since nothing was working I was trying different things. Unfortunately this still doesn't work in my code. I am using Nuxt with the composition API ''@nuxtjs/composition-api' and weirdly same code thats working in codesandbox with your suggestions in vue doesnt work in my Nuxt build.

Comment: @AndyJamesN That's using the composition API plugin for Vue 2 so relies on the old reactivity system (i.e. not using proxies). It'll therefore suffer from the same [reactivity gotchas](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Objects).

Comment: Here is a sandbox using nuxt https://codesandbox.io/s/nuxt-composition-api-usemeta-layout-issue-forked-7ui2m

Comment: @HusamIbrahim Ah well that would explain it. On the Nuxt page https://composition-api.nuxtjs.org it says "Vue 3 Composition API
Get all the Composition API features in Nuxt 2." I guess that comes with some not so obvious caveats.

Comment: What I am going to do as a workaround is use Vuex store instead. This will allow me to edit my main color object (which is in reality much more complex than just colors) as needed and use computed to keep things reactive. Thanks for all the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

your colors object and function should be like this

```
 const colors = reactive({ green: "#ccc000" });
    function addColor() {
      colors.green = "rgb(23, 117, 109)";
    }
```

don't forget to return colors and addColor from setup

in your template add

```
<pre>{{ colors.green }}</pre>
    <button @click="addColor">add color</button>
```

this should work

Answer (score 0):

By doing so first:

`colors = Object.assign({}, colors, { red: '#fff000' });`

You damage the reactivity

Now this absolutely appropriate line of code `colors.orange = '#322332'`   does not work since the reactivity already lost

The solution is - remove the first attempt